# How much string objects are created (String.format())?

Tags: java, string, instance

After a dispute with my colleague we couldn't find a solution. So my question

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    String.format("Variable i = %d", i);
}
```

How much variables will be created during running this code?
I have an opinion, that here can be created 4 variables:

1. "Variable i = %d",
2. "Variable i = %d" - on both cycle steps will be created an object for formatting
3. "Variable i = 0",
4. "Variable i = 1" - resulted strings.

am I right?

Comment: stackOverFlowers! :)

Comment: Do you mean to ask how many _strings_ are created? If so, the answer is three.

Comment: I'm guessing, 0. As the format operator just replaces it's respective object. %d is just replaced by i.

Comment: your question is not clear, are you counting the number of Variables or the number of Strings created  ? please be specific ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"Variable i = %d"` is a string literal, so it will be put in the string pool and not created twice. Hence, you'll have a total of three strings:
`"Variable i = %d"`, `"Variable i = 0"` and `"Variable i = 1"`.

Comment: I thought he was asking about the number of variables created, not strings

Comment: That's not how I understood the question. @pasha-shtefanesku could you clarify if this was what you were asking?

Comment: @UmaLakshmiKanth what *number of variables* could even mean?

Comment: I'm asking about count of created string objects.

Comment: @PashaShtefanesku then this should answer your question

Comment: but this instruction  `String.format("Variable i = %d", i);`  will be called twice so *"Variable i = %d"* will be created twice ?,!!!

Comment: or put in the pool twice ? no